# Plugin Typo 3 Text box slide open

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, typo3

Are there plugins that achieve the following:
You can add text blocks into a section of a page (left, right, normal,bottom). the text isnt shown ommediately but after clicking the title/header of the text block which slides open the text. I'm in need of such an extension as I want to place much content on a site without throwing the whole text on a viewer. There seem not to ve any available.

Comment: Such a thing is typically self-built in TYPO3, because you just need to print out some HTML and use some JS and CSS to style, hide and show it. Also, designs for the same content can be very different in TYPO3, so it's not so easy to do this as a general-purpose plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default TYPO3 doesn't force any particular frontend library so probably you won't find such ext (maybe somebody created extension like this but for 99% it will be required to fit it tou your needs)

Instead there are generic extensions like [**Grid Elements**](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gridelements) or [**Dynamic Content Elements (DCE)**](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce) - you can use it to predefine your custom HTML structures and then reuse them easily (no need for advanced PHP programming of your own plugins).

So finally you can combine them with dedicated JS libs for frontend i.e. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and its [Accordion Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Comment: there are also dedicated plugins for gridelements which do just that, bootstrap_core and bootstrap_grids

Answer (score 0):

If you use TYPO3 6.2 or higher have a look at [df_contentslide](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/df_contentslide). After install you'll find another section under appearance in CEs. Now you can slide every content element. It is easy to use and with little knowledge also easy to style.